# ListView only showing first result - only in mobile device : MasterDetail View

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, master-detail

I have this problem in my detail view in my `Master/Detail` Template based app. 
im populating expandable list in detail view. it is working fine in tablet view. but in mobile device it is only showing me first result only. i even tried removing `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to make sure listview not getting block by any other scroll options. but i couldn't find the problem.

#### Setting up adapter

```
ArrayList<ClientList> clientLists = ClientList.getClientList(getActivity(), clientResult);
Log.e("Client","--"+clientLists.size()); //Im getting the list size as normal 
clientExpandableAdapter = new ClientExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), clientLists);
expandableListView.setAdapter(clientExpandableAdapter);
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, int i1, long l) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

#### Detail view layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xxx.xxx.ItemDetailFragment"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
            android:id="@+id/mainViewHeader">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/titleHeader"
            android:text="Clients" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/titleCountHeader"
            android:text="Clients"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainViewHeader"
        android:id="@+id/backgroundView"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/mainExpandableDatalist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ExpandableListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this type of issues many mistakes are possible according to me.

1. You might have taken ScrollView as parent of listview which is not at all required.
2. Height of ListView or custom ListView layout's root element could be `match_parent | fill_parent` that shows single item in whole screen.

It will be better if you show layout files too.

Comment: I tried changing layout heights as you suggested. still no success. btw i have updated the question with layout file

Comment: I found the problem. problem was in ExpandableListView Height. once i gave custom height. data started to showing. but its cofusing why its only occuring in mobile device

Comment: Your modified question with code is alright,
but again it is depended on the layout that you have created for custom list view.
If parent of ExpandableCustomListView layout's height is match_parent then it also covers single item in full screen.